# android suggestion on zooming

Tags: android

I have to zoom particular area or particular pixels in picture when touched.

Please suggest how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

you can find an article about similar issue [here](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-2-building-the-touch-example/1763) and the sources containing very cool example on which this article is based are free to get.
Have a fun.